# Unmarshal array json in golang

Tags: json, go

How would I unmarshal something like this:

```
[
2,
"19223201",
"SomeString",
{
    "SomeField": "FieldValue",
    "SomeField2": "FieldValue2", "SomeFieldN": "FieldValueN",       }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `interface{}` if you have not define any interface and unmarshal into interface type slice.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func main() {

    strBytes := []byte(`[2,"19223201", "SomeString",{"SomeField": "FieldValue","SomeField2": "FieldValue2", "SomeFieldN": "FieldValueN"}]`)
    keys := make([]interface{},0)

    json.Unmarshal(strBytes, &keys)
    fmt.Println(keys)

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Life saver.

Comment: Full working example including parsing the map that golang creates for the object {} -> if anyone come across this:
https://play.golang.org/p/xDAo1MSjdY